# CodeMix/Eclipse cannot find 'react/jsx-dev-runtime'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm completely new to React, Node, NPM, and CodeMix in Eclipse.  I'm a veteran java developer and so want to use eclipse over VSCode for familiarity. I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.genuitec.com/react-tutorial-getting-started/

I get to step 5 and run

```
react-scripts start
```

The result:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' in 'C:\temp\workspace\CCFPortal\src'
```

I created my project via the new project to create a React project. The wizard added all the standard code.  Bringing up the terminal gave me some issues because the terminal doesn't seem to set the path to bring nodejs.exe into scope, so I did it manually in the terminal window. Adjusting the properties in window->preferences terminal+ doesn't seem to ever take effect.

I did the following in npm (in addition to the steps in the tutorial) because there were two 'warnings' in the markers view that suggested it. As near as I can tell, all commands were successful whether from the tutorial or these two (though it does flag some 'vulnerabilities' in npm that I force fixed).

```
npm install @types/react
npm install @types/react-dom
```

It is indeed true that there is no react/jsx-dev-runtime under that src folder.  There's NOTHING there but the src.  But I'm unclear why it wasn't there given that I ran npm install and the other things suggested in the tutorial.

Can someone help explain my pathing issue in the terminal and especially why npm is doing this when I run react-scripts start?

Comment: CodeMix is not Eclipse, but a properitary plugin. The Eclipse plugin that provides support for React is [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper).

Comment: I'm having the same issue after adding  "type": "module"  in package.json and I'm using the Webstorm IDE.